# Neon 4x4 transpose

Tags: assembly, matrix, arm, transpose

The AARCH32 Neon programmer's guide makes the following statement:

> Use multiple VTRN instructions to transpose larger matrices. For
> example, a 4x4 matrix consisting of 16-bit elements can be transposed
> using three VTRN instructions.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this with three VTRN instructions. Even if I assume other instructions are allowed (within reason), I don't see a solution. Anyone know what the NPG is talking about? Is this a mistake, or is it some incredibly tricky sequence I'm just not seeing?
Thanks

Comment: 4x4 x 16-bit elements is 32 bytes of data, fitting in 2 Q vectors.  I'd guess the pattern might be something like one 16-byte VTRN between the Q vectors and two 8-byte VTRN between the D halves of those results, taking advantage of 32-bit ARM's partial-register shenanigans where both halves of a Q vector are accessible as D halves.  Or maybe the other way around, maybe two `vtrn.16 d, d` feeding a `vtrn.16 q,q` or .32

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as speculated in the comment:

```
//       d0      d1
// q0 = |0 1 2 3|4 5 6 7|
//       d2      d3
// q1 = |8 9 a b|c d e f|
//
trn.16  d0, d1
//      |0 4 2 6|1 5 3 7|
trn.16  d2, d3
//      |8 c a e|9 d b f|
trn.32  q0, q1
//      |0 4 8 c|1 5 9 d| q0
//      |2 6 a e|3 7 b f| q1
```

In ARM32 (v7) an instruction can modify both operands (like in `swp`, contrary to arm64, which only has a single target register.

Comment: It's even possible to transpose 4x4 in two instructions on v7 using either two successive uzp or two successive zip operations of `vzip.16 q0,q1; vzip.16 q0,q1;` or `vuzp.16 q0,q1; vuzp.16 q0,q1;`.